# Showing that if $y(x)$ is a solution, then $y(-x)$ is also a solution for a specific ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given the ODE $(1-x^2)y''-xy'+\alpha^2 y=0$, I need to show that if $y(x)$ is a solution, then $y(-x)$ is also a solution. From what I understand, because $y(0)=y(-0)$, it means that *all* solutions are even functions.

I solved the ODE using series around $x=0$ which is a regular point.

I got:

$$y(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_nx^n$$
Where

$$a_{2n}=\frac {\pi_{k=0}^n ((2k)^2-\alpha ^2)}{(2n)!}a_0$$
$$a_{2n+1}=\frac {\pi_{k=0}^n ((2k+1)^2-\alpha ^2)}{(2n+1)!}a_1$$
$a_0$, $a_1$ are determined by the starting conditions.

I don't see how this solution is even.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you replace $x$ by $z = -x$ and write $y(x) = g(z)$ then the differential equation becomes $(1-z^2)g''-zg'+\alpha^2 g=0$, so that $g(z)$ satisifies the same equation as $y(x)$.